# Library with react Higher Order Components and react-redux throws Error: Invalid hook call only when redux connect func is used

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, react-hooks, higher-order-components

I'm writing a library to provide some basic Higher Order Components for use in our company's React apps. The gist is the HOCs will pull in some toggles from our redux state and conditionally render components or inject props (depending on the HOC used).

I get the `Error: Invalid hook call.` error only when I'm using the `connect` function inside the HOCs. They can return/render a React component supplied as an argument with no error. I originally thought this could be due to having mismatched versions of React or duplicate React versions, but since it will render/return React components just fine I think it has to do with trying to connect to redux.

And I have confirmed there is a toggle key in the redux state obj, the library is pulling in react-redux (the `connect` function is not undefined), and the HOC works as expected if I copy the code into the React app itself rather than import from the library.

Here is an example of a HOC from the library:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { selectToggles } from "../redux";

export const ComponentBranch = (
  testFunc: (toggles: any) => boolean,
  ComponentA: React.ComponentType,
  ComponentB: React.ComponentType,
) => {
  const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
      toggles: selectToggles(state),
    }
  };

  const WithToggleComponent = ({ toggles }: any, ...props: any) => {
    return testFunc(toggles) ? <ComponentA {...props} /> : <ComponentB {...props} />;
  };

  return connect<ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>, undefined>(mapStateToProps)(WithToggleComponent);
};
```

and how it's being used in the React app:

```
  //...
  const PageTitleA = ({ sub }: any) => <div><PageTitle>Title A {sub}</PageTitle></div>
  const PageTitleB = ({ sub }: any) => <div><PageTitle>Title B {sub}</PageTitle></div>

  const RenderTitle = ComponentBranch(
    () => true,
    PageTitleA,
    PageTitleB,
  )

  return (
    <Container>
      <RenderTitle sub="sub title here!" />
    //...
```

In the library's `package.json`, I'm including `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-redux` as devDependencies and peerDependencies. In the `webpack.config.js`, I'm including them in the `externals` property:

```
externals: {
      react: {
          root: 'React',
          commonjs2: 'react',
          commonjs: 'react',
          amd: 'react'
      },
      'react-dom': {
          root: 'ReactDOM',
          commonjs2: 'react-dom',
          commonjs: 'react-dom',
          amd: 'react-dom'
      },
      'react-redux': {
        root: 'ReactRedux',
        commonjs2: 'react-redux',
        commonjs: 'react-redux',
        amd: 'react-redux',
      },
      'redux': {
        root: 'Redux',
        commonjs2: 'redux',
        commonjs: 'redux',
        amd: 'redux',
      }
    }
```

I get this error regardless of whether I'm linking in the library locally, or installing through npm.

If I remove the use of redux in the library component, and just return the components it works just fine, but of course I need to use redux:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { selectToggles } from "../redux";

export const ComponentBranch = (
  testFunc: (toggles: any) => boolean,
  ComponentA: React.ComponentType,
  ComponentB: React.ComponentType,
) => {
  const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
      toggles: selectToggles(state),
    }
  };

  const WithToggleComponent = (...props: any) => {
    //return testFunc(toggles) ? <ComponentA {...props} /> : <ComponentB {...props} />;

    return [<ComponentA {...props} /> : <ComponentB {...props} />];
  };

  //return connect<ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>, undefined>(mapStateToProps)(WithToggleComponent);

  return <WithToggleComponent />
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: if you use functional components why don't you use redux hooks there instead of mapStateToProps etc. ? isn't it easier option?

Comment: connect offers better performance than the redux hooks, so while we use functional components we opt to use the connect func with mapStateToProps for the perf gain which is worth it for us since we rely heavily on redux at the moment.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your issue: [reduxhoc library](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/reduxhoc) and [reduxhoc example (uses library)](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/reduxhoc-example). Since you haven't provided a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) my guess is that your bundler is not configured properly and is compiling an invalid React component.

Comment: @MattCarlotta I was wrong before and it was in fact a React version mismatch. The error was also true if I tried using hooks (took out the connect function and tossed in a useState hook). Once I got both the app and the lib using the same version of React the error went away. I really appreciate you taking the time to look into this.

Comment: @JTP709 No problem. A word of caution: Be careful about using the `any` type in your HOC. It opens the flood gates to passing an invalid prop to your composed components.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong before and it was in fact a React version mismatch. The error was also true if I tried using hooks (took out the connect function and tossed in a useState hook). Once I got both the app and the lib using the same version of React the error went away.